# C# How to extract complete xml node set

Tags: c#, xpath, c#-3.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <bookstore>
  <book category="COOKING"> 
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>    
    <year>2005</year>
   <price>30.00</price>
  </book>

  <book category="CHILDREN">
   <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
   <author>J K. Rowling</author>
   <year>2005</year>
   <price>29.99</price>
  </book>

  <book category="WEB">
   <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
   <author>James McGovern</author>
   <author>Per Bothner</author>
   <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
   <author>James Linn</author>
   <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
   <year>2003</year>
   <price>49.99</price>
  </book>

  <book category="WEB">
   <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
   <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
   <year>2003</year>
   <price>39.95</price>
  </book>

</bookstore>
```

Is their any way using XPath to select the complete first node set, for example from

```
 <book category="COOKING">  
  to 
 </book>,
```

so that, that chunk of xml can be stored for later use.

Bob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say this XML is stored in an `XmlDocument` called `doc`.

```
XmlElement docRoot = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode cookingNode = docRoot.SelectSingleNode("./book[@category='COOKING']");
```

I tested this and added this line to verify:

```
Console.WriteLine(cookingNode.OuterXml);
```

Here was the output:

```
<book category="COOKING"><title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title><author>Giada
De Laurentiis</author><year>2005</year><price>30.00</price></book>
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will select that node.  Are you trying to get a set of nodes or just the single one?  You might have to put the bookstore node back yourself if you only want th subset of nodes.

```
/bookstore/book[@category='COOKING']
```

as XmlDocument ...

```
var x = new XmlDocument();
x.Load("XmlFile1.xml");
var ns = x.SelectSingleNode("/bookstore/book[@category='COOKING']");

var res = ns.OuterXml;
```

as XDocument ...

```
var x = XDocument.Load("XmlFile1.xml");

var root = new XElement("bookstore",
    from book in x.Element("bookstore").Elements("book")
    where book.Attribute("category").Value == "COOKING"
    select book
    );
```

if you just want the book node you can do this instead of the root version above

```
var book = x.Element("bookstore")
    .Elements("book")
    .Where(n => n.Attribute("category").Value == "COOKING")
    .First();
```

Comment: I've tried that. That only brings back the "COOKING NODE". What I want is to bring back everything that is inside that particular block from <book category="Coooking"> to ... <book />

Comment: I'm reading xml messages coming into a message pipe. I need to store specific parts of them, so those parts can be built up into a new composite message, essentially a request/reply. So I need a way to picking selected chunks of xml from incoming messages to be used at a later date to build the reply message.

Comment: I am getting the entire node with SelectNode and SelectSingleNode.  The Xml.Linq classes are working the same.

Comment: @scope-creep: From `var ns = x.SelectSingleNode([...])`, you should be able to access the nodes inside that node with `ns.ChildNodes`.

Comment: Also you can check the .OuterXml it will show you the node you are on.  If you sheck .InnerXML it will only show you the children.

Answer (score 1):

suppose I want to extract only the data wherethe xml file is as follows ..

```
<book category="COOKING"> 
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author auth="up">Giada De Laurentiis</author>    
    <year>2005</year>
   <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
```

the final result on the list view should look like this

```
  lang       auth
  en          up
```

I have coded as follows ..

```
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("book");
                    for (int j = 0; j < elemList.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (elemList[j].Attributes["category"].Value == "COOKING")
                        {
                            XmlNodeList elemList1 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("author");
                            for (int i = 0; i < elemList1.Count; i++)
                            {
                                string attrVal = elemList1[i].Attributes["lang"].Value;
                                string attrVal1 = elemList1[i].Attributes["auth"].Value;

                                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

                                    lvi.SubItems.Add(attrVal1);
                                    lvi.SubItems.Add(attrVal1);
                                }
                                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: finally I hav the code for the requirement I had ..
        `XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
// (Put code to populate xDoc here)
XmlNodeList xNode = xDoc.SelectNodes(@"/bookstore/book[@category='COOKING']/title");`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Matthew's response:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
// (Put code to populate xDoc here)
XmlNodeList xNode = xDoc.SelectNodes(@"/bookstore/book[@category='COOKING']");
```

xNode now equals Book of type COOKING.

Comment: I think that'll give you an `XmlNodeList` rather than an `XmlNode`.

Comment: Yeah... you will need to get the first index or use SelectSingleNode