# How to remove the soap headers and additional tags to retrieve the desired xml?

Tags: java, xml, soap, xpath

This is the xml i have in the string format.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:processRequestResponse xmlns:ns="http://service.soap.oneflexi.com"><ns:return>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ItemRs language="SG" currency="SGD"> 
  <Items>
 <Item>
   <CategoryCode />
    <CategoryDescription />
   <ItemCode>356</ItemCode>
    <ItemDescription>20% offer, Latest model</ItemDescription>
   <Quantity />
    <UnitPrice>24560</UnitPrice>
    <ItemBigImagesURL>http://goo.gl/klCGG4</ItemBigImagesURL>
    <ItemContent>Front Loading Washing Machine 6.5Kg Capacity 6 Motion Direct Drive</ItemContent>
   <ErrorCode />
    <ErrorMessage />
    <Beaconid>2499</Beaconid>
  </Item>
  </Items>
 <MID />
 </ItemRs>
</ns:return>
</ns:processRequestResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and the output i need should be subset of the above xml removing the soap headers and other tags. How can i achieve this output in java?

```
<ItemRs language="SG" currency="SGD"> 
  <Items>
 <Item>
   <CategoryCode />
    <CategoryDescription />
   <ItemCode>356</ItemCode>
    <ItemDescription>20% offer, Latest model</ItemDescription>
   <Quantity />
    <UnitPrice>24560</UnitPrice>
    <ItemBigImagesURL>http://goo.gl/klCGG4</ItemBigImagesURL>
    <ItemContent>Front Loading Washing Machine 6.5Kg Capacity 6 Motion Direct Drive</ItemContent>
   <ErrorCode />
    <ErrorMessage />
    <Beaconid>2499</Beaconid>
  </Item>
  </Items>
 <MID />
 </ItemRs>
```

Please any help would be appreciated and Thanks in advance.

I have tried using the example given in this thread : [1]:[Java How to extract a complete XML block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979851/java-how-to-extract-a-complete-xml-block).

Here is the java code

```
public static void main(String... args)
    throws Exception
    {
//      String xml = "<A><B><id>0</id></B><B><id>1</id></B></A>";
        String xml =    "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ser=\"http://service.soap.oneflexi.com\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><ser:processRequest><ser:in0><![CDATA[<BconRq language=\"SG\" currency=\"SGD\"><RqHeader><Date>20140614</Date><Time>162944</Time><TimeZone>GMT+06:00</TimeZone><MessageType>5320</MessageType><VersionNo>9005001</VersionNo><AppVersion>5.0.1</AppVersion><MerchantId>2003001</MerchantId><TerminalId>2004002</TerminalId><StanNo/><LastTxnRefNo/><OTP/></RqHeader><OfferMerchant/><OfferFlag>Y</OfferFlag><BconId>1234</BconId><Items><Item><ItemCode>VC01</ItemCode></Item></Items></BconRq>]]></ser:in0><ser:in4>?</ser:in4></ser:processRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Node result = (Node)xPath.evaluate(" Soapenv:Envelope/Soapenv:Body/ns:processRequestResponse/ns:return/BconRs[language=\"SG\"]", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

//      Node result = (Node)xPath.evaluate("A/B[id = '1']", doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
//  Soapenv:Envelope/Soapenv:Body/ns:processRequestResponse/ns:return/BconRs[language="SG"]
        System.out.println(nodeToString(result));
    }

    private static String nodeToString(Node node)
    throws TransformerException
    {
        StringWriter buf = new StringWriter();
        Transformer xform = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        xform.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(buf));
        return(buf.toString());
    }
```

I probably think there may be an error in XPATH traversing to the node **ItemRs**.

Comment: Show us the Java code you have tried.

Comment: You can try XML parsers http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html or in the last case use regex

Comment: @Tichodroma: i have added the code i have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you also suspected, the XPath looks incorrect. You may want to try this simple XPath :

```
//ItemRs[@language='SG']
```

To reference an attribute in XPath, you need to use `@` at the beginning of the attribute name. And I try to avoid mentioning namespace prefixes in XPath because usually we need to register namespace prefix-to-namespace URI mapping somehow (and I'm not sure on how to do this in Java, I am more into .NET).