# XML Value of a node while parsing using DOM

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I am trying to get the XML value of a node.

To get the Nodelist i am doing this

```
NodeList list =  (NodeList) doc.getElementsByTagName("response")
```

To get particular Node I am doing:

```
list.item(index);
```

From the node i can get the text content of the node but I don't know how to get the XML String value of a node.

For example:

```
<add job="351">
<test>
<tag>foobar</tag>
<tag>foobar2</tag>
</test>
</add>
```

I can pick the node with tag "test". Now from the Node i want output like this:

```
<test>
<tag>foobar</tag>
<tag>foobar2</tag>
</test>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting XML Node text value with Java DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773012/getting-xml-node-text-value-with-java-dom)

Comment: Its not duplicate, actually i want XML String value of a node.

Comment: Then clarify your question. "XML value of a node" and "text content of a node" are same. Do you need the name of the XML attribute? Then write it, please.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: [Java How to extract a complete XML block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980018/5538979)

Comment: @hadi.mansouri Yes it worked  thank you :)