# extract an element out of an XML document while preserving namespace prefix definitions

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to extract an element (as a String) out of an XML document. I have tried both approaches suggested [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219806/274677) (a similar method is also suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980018/274677)) and they both fail to properly account for namespace prefixes that may be defined in some outer-level document.

Using the following code:

```
// entry point method; see exampes of values for the String `s` in the question
public static String stripPayload(String s) throws Exception {
    final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    final Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(s)));

    final XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    final String xPathToGetToTheNodeWeWishToExtract = "/*[local-name()='envelope']/*[local-name()='payload']";
    final Node result = (Node) xPath.evaluate(xPathToGetToTheNodeWeWishToExtract, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
    return nodeToString_A(result); // or: nodeToString_B(result)

}

public static String nodeToString_A(Node node) throws Exception {
    final StringWriter buf = new StringWriter();
    final Transformer xform = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
    xform.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(buf));
    return(buf.toString());
}

public static String nodeToString_B(Node node) throws Exception {
    final Document document = node.getOwnerDocument();
    final DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();
    final LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
    final String str = serializer.writeToString(node);
    return str;
}
```

If the `stripPayload` method if passed the following strings:

```
<envelope><payload><a></a><b></b></payload></envelope>
```

or

```
<envelope><p:payload xmlns:p='foo'><a></a><b></b></p:payload></envelope>
```

… both `nodeToString_A` and `nodeToString_B` methods work. However, if I pass the following equally valid XML document where the namespace prefix is defined in an outer element:

```
<envelope xmlns:p='foo'><p:payload><a></a><b></b></p:payload></envelope>
```

… then both methods fail as they simply emit:

```
<p:payload><a/><b/></p:payload>
```

Thus, they are already producing an invalid document as the namespace prefix definition is left out.

The more complicated example below (which uses namespace prefixes in attributes):

```
<envelope xmlns:p='foo' xmlns:a='alpha'><p:payload a:attr='dummy'><a></a><b></b></p:payload></envelope>
```

… actually causes `nodeToString_A` to fail with an exception whereas at least `nodeToString_B` produces the invalid:

```
<p:payload a:attr="dummy"><a/><b/></p:payload>
```

(where again, the prefixes are not defined).

So my question is:

What is a robust way to extract and stringify an inner XML element in a way that takes care of namespace prefixes that may be defined in some outer element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to enable *name-space-awareness*.

```
public static String stripPayload(String s) throws Exception {
    final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

    ...
}
```

The output will be ...

```
<p:payload xmlns:p="foo"><a/><b/></p:payload>
```